# Is there a way to fetch the price of an item on the steam library?

Tags: python, steam

I have looked for a way to fetch the price of an item on steam with python, everything I have looked at many different methods but most I dont understand.

I have tried:

```
import requests
cookie = {'steamLogin': '#####'}    
data = requests.get('http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/? 
country=PT&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Falchion%20Case', 
cookies=cookie);
print(data.text)
```

But it outputs an empty array. 
I have seen questions but i have not found the answers very clear.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Reasonably sure that you don't wanna be sharing the login to steam

Comment: Have you tried getting it from something like https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=730 ?

Comment: @roganjosh heh yeah meant to edit that out must've forgotten

Comment: Done now. I tried to edit, then you edited too. But it cannot be hidden now, you'll need to change the login if that's impacted (I don't use Steam tbh)

Comment: @snowjin Yes, your Steam credentials live forever in the edit history. Change them ASAP if you haven't already!

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar  yeah, but it's just my web API key